# how to set background-image of list items in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple div with bunch of list items that I need to set their background with javascript? any help would be highly appreciate it, let say I have url1, url2, url3, url4?

```
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li style="background-image: url('img/sunset.jpg');">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>The jQuery slider that just slides.</h1>
        <p>No fancy effects or unnecessary markup, and it’s less than 3kb.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#download">Download</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li style="background-image: url('img/wood.jpg');">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Fluid, flexible, fantastically minimal.</h1>
        <p>Use any HTML in your slides, extend with CSS. You have full control.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#download">Download</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li style="background-image: url('img/subway.jpg');">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Open-source.</h1>
        <p>Everything to do with Unslider is hosted on GitHub.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="//github.com/idiot/unslider">Contribute</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li style="background-image: url('img/shop.jpg');">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Uh, that’s about it.</h1>
        <p>I just wanted to show you another slide.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#download">Download</a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `list-style-image` in CSS? [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be to create separate CSS classes for each of the background image styles you want. Then you can use a library like jQuery to addClass to any HTML element. Here's the jQuery documentation: [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Ideally, you want to avoid convoluting your CSS with JavaScript code and as much as possible, keep these two separate from each other.